# Issue related to Keeping Jquery in Separate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some javascript functions added in .js file and also added following Jquery function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("aj");
            $(".QDContactDetails").click(function (event) {
               alert("Clicked !!!");
            });

        });
```

i wonder that javascript functions call properly but above jquery lines doesn't work.. what is problem in above code? how can i put Jquery in .js file.. 
i am using newly version of Jquery1.7

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens? What doesn't happen that you expect? What error messages are reported by your debug tool? jQuery is a JS library. You use it (and put it in files) like any other piece of JS code.

Comment: Make sure you add this piece of code after loading jQuery library.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't execute? Have you set a breakpoint in a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work fine. You just need to ensure that you place the reference to jQuery first, then your own external js file references after that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-jquery-code.js"></script>
```